# convert dataframe to list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
                     value
time
2016-12-01 00:00:00          NaN
2016-12-01 00:01:00          2
2016-12-01 00:02:00          1
```

I want convert this dataframe to a list of lists, likes this:

```
[['2016-12-01 00:00:00', NaN],['2016-12-01 00:01:00', 2],['2016-12-01 00:02:00', 1]]
```

I tried `df.values` or `df.values.tolist()` and always receive:

```
[[ nan]
 [   2]
 [   1]]
```

Answer (score 13):

If you call [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) to restore the index, you can then call `.values.tolist()` to get the desired result:

```
In [117]:
df.reset_index().values.tolist()

Out[117]:

[['2016-12-01 00:00:00', nan],
 ['2016-12-01 00:01:00', 2.0],
 ['2016-12-01 00:02:00', 1.0]]
```

[`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) returns a numpy array, this has a method [`tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) to convert to a list of lists

Answer (score 6):

Need [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) first, [`DataFrame.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) return `numpy array` and `tolist()` convert it to `nested list`:

```
print (df.index)
Index(['2016-12-01 00:00:00', '2016-12-01 00:01:00', '2016-12-01 00:02:00'], 
 dtype='object', name='time')


print (df.reset_index().values.tolist())
[['2016-12-01 00:00:00', nan], ['2016-12-01 00:01:00', 2.0], ['2016-12-01 00:02:00', 1.0]]
```

But if [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) is necessary convert `index` to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-12-01 00:00:00', '2016-12-01 00:01:00',
               '2016-12-01 00:02:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)

print (df.reset_index().values.tolist())
[[Timestamp('2016-12-01 00:00:00'), nan], 
  [Timestamp('2016-12-01 00:01:00'), 2.0], 
  [Timestamp('2016-12-01 00:02:00'), 1.0]]

df.index = df.index.astype(str)
print (df.reset_index().values.tolist())
[['2016-12-01 00:00:00', nan], ['2016-12-01 00:01:00', 2.0], ['2016-12-01 00:02:00', 1.0]]
```